# using scale and transform together for an object

Tags: css

How can I use both transform's scale and translate method with css?

```
body{
  transform: scale(.5);
  transform: translate(-50%,0);
}
```

Obviously, the above css rule (the last one) overrides the previous line of rule `transform: scale(.5)` and it just applies translate.

So, is there any way that I can use both for an object?

<sub>Here object means the group of divs.</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put them together.

```
body{
  transform: scale(.5) translate(-50%,0);
}
```

Comment: Oh! It can be used together. I didn't know about that. Thanks. Works great.

Comment: Yes, you can. You're Welcome!